# Skipped cell in bootstrap image grid Firefox and IE 11 Only

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, cross-browser

The image at the bottom shows a bootstrap grid representation of 6 275.5px images. Where the blank space is, should be additional images, they were skipped for an unknown reason. In this entire grid there is about 70 images, when on a 4 column it occurs at image #40. On a 3 column, it occurs at image #39. On a 2 column, this issue does not exist. This only happens on IE11 and Firefox, not Chrome. Every image is the same size, there is no variety in each cell.

- Bootstrap v3.3.7
- normalize.css v5.0.0
- AngularJS v1.4.8
- ng-directive-lazy-image

The pattern is that when the page is loaded, angular makes a call to an .ashx handler that returns JSON. The JSON is bound to repeating divs with the bootstrap styling. The JSON being returned is clean as is the markup. There is no junk data in-between these 2 cells. There is some lazy loading for the images, just in case that could be a potential root cause. There are no errors in the F12 debugger, although Firefox complains about styling directives given by bootstrap.css which is probably a known occurence.

Example JSON

```
[{
"id": "Product 1",
"order": 1,
"thumbnailUrl": "http://local.testsite.com/~/media/19F6.ashx"
},
{
"id": "Product 2",
"order": 2,
"thumbnailUrl": "http://local.testsite.com/~/media/9557.ashx"
}]
```

Example markup that was generated. You get 1 div like this for every product.

```
<div class="col-xs1-home-6 col-xs2-home-4 col-sm-home-6 
col-md-home-4 col-lg-home-3 ng-scope" ng-repeat="brand in ctrl.brands">                  
  <a href="#/gradeline?brand=Product1" 
  ui-sref="gradeline({ brand: brand.id })">
    <img src="http://local.testsite.com/~/media/19F6.ashx" 
    ng-src="http://local.testsite.com/~/media/9557.ashx">
  </a>             
</div>
```

I have tried adding entries to the database, so that the cells were divisible by 4, just in case it was trying to make the last cell fall in the 4th column. This did not help. I also tried some commonly known 'clear fix' styles to denote the end of the row.

[image: Missing cell items]

Comment: See the image src, it contain ~ character, you don't need this, it is not asp.net application.

Comment: Pay no mind to that. This is in fact an ASP.NET app with Sitecore 6.6 on top of it. These products are coming from Commerce Server 2009. For the purposes of this question that's all abstracted away by the ashx handler which is giving us the JSON. The ~ you see is how it gets at images in the media library for Sitecore. We do the same thing on another app like this, but its enough of a different animal that we can't reproduce the same grid issue.